# node-postgres script does not end after it is finished

Tags: node.js, node-postgres, node-pg-pool

I have a script called `scheduler()` which runs some queries on a Postgres database and then finished. I am having a problem where the script hangs in the terminal and does not exit after.

Here is my code:

scheduler.js

```
const {pool} = require("./db");
const scheduler = async function() {
    try {
        await auctionCheck();
        return pool.end().then(() => {
            console.log('Pool\'s closed');
            return;
        })

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
        return;
    }

}
return scheduler();
```

db.js

```
const {Pool} = require("pg");
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
});

pool.on('error', (err, client) => {
    console.error('Unexpected error on idle client', err)
    process.exit(-1)
})

pool.connect();

module.exports = {pool};
```

When I didn't have the `pool.end()` call, my script didn't exit, but it does not exit with the `end()` call either. The "Pool's closed" log is never printed. [node-pg documentation](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool) says that I should do this to close connections (I assume that the reason my script isn't finishing is due to an open db connection.) I want to basically run some functions periodically and then have the script finish, but currently it just stays live. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the reason was that in `db.js` I had `pool.connect()`. Thus, when I did `pool.end()`, it couldn't close the connection because it did not have all of the clients in the pool - one being already created in `db.js` but never released. When I removed `pool.connect()` in `db.js` the process exited as it should.

Comment: You may have used the `pool.connect()` method but it is important that the returned client is released by calling `client.release()`. I assume that once the client is released the `pool.end()` function would terminate as well.